# SaaS Application and ORM in PHP (RedBean)

Tags: php, orm, redbean

**Context**

As a hobby I'm building a SaaS application that would be able to extract the configuration of a CRM application (Customer Relationship Management) and maybe if I succeed I plan on making it publicly available.

I have developed a set of PHP files to extract the configuration and even though this was quite tough, I succeeded and I can now browse the retrieved objects.

I can serialize those objects and save it as files but that would not be possible to release such an application because of the I/O and time wasted to treat all those transactions (as I see it).

So I have my set of files (serialized objects with 1:M relationships between them most of the time) and I decided to create PDOManager files to perform CRUD on the database depending on the data I extract from the CRM (automated process using webservices).

The objects I retrieve and thus my classes are subject to evolution so it's not written in stone and fields can be added / removed based on the functionalities implemented in the future releases of the CRM

Question to ORM and PHP users:

- Is that a good idea (granted that data model can evolve) to create a set of PHP files to CRUD the database with PDO manually?
- Or is it a total waste of time and I should let an ORM take care of all this and create a database with all my objects?

**Clarification**

This is the process I am implementing and where I am currently in this process

1. Get WSDL files from the CRM (23 different wsdl for every component of the CRM)
2. Query the CRM using webservices
3. Get the XML answers for the queried webservices (those XML files contain the configuration characteristics)
4. Create objects to model the configuration data and store temporarily the different occurences of objects to arrays.
5. Save those arrays to a database.

Once this is all done, the purpose is to allow users of the service to retrieve their configuration data in Excel files or so (maybe a web interface but at a later stage).

---

I have currently completed up to step 4 programmatically and I was wondering what I should do for step 5. The options I see here are:

A. Create a DBManager to save the configuration objects, this would force me to model the DB, create tables columns and constraints, create readers / writers for the objects to the database. There are 52 tables in the model I drafted.

B. Use an ORM that may (if I understood well) create all the tables, columns and constraints based on the links between my objects. This looks like magic to me because I have never used or heard about ORM prior to yesterday.

Help me make an educated choice.

Comment: What is the purpose of serialising the configuration objects you have retrieved? (It may be better to clarify that in your question, rather than commenting at length).

Comment: That said, it looks like your question is: should you use an ORM? Such a question is difficult to answer here, since without a spec and the source code, readers are not in possession of sufficient detail to answer. Personally, I think ORMs are worthwhile - they generally add more productivity than they reduce performance. However, this is (a) subjective and (b) it depends.

Comment: Halfer, thanks for your answer. 1- There is no point in serializing the objects at this point (apart from storing objects in files for a later use). 2- I'm editing my first question to add in more explanation about the process and let you answer.